# Commas in questions with two options

Tags: пунктуация

> -- Не знаю куда мне пойти, на правый берег или на левый.
>
> -- Да какая разница, на правый или на левый.

Do I need these commas here?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, those commas are required. Rosenthal:

> § 22. Уточняющие члены предложения
>
> Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже — тире) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому). Чаще всего уточняются обстоятельства и определения.
>
> 1. Уточняющие обстоятельства места: Там, ниже, мох тощий, кустарник седой (П.); Внизу, в тени, шумел Дунай (Тютч.); Илья Ильич учился в Верхлёве, верстах в пяти от Обломовки, у тамошнего управляющего немца Штольца (Гонч.); Прямо против кордона, на том берегу, всё было пусто (Л. Т.); [...]

In your examples the word being clarified (уточняемое слово) is куда. In the second example it is implied: Да какая разница [куда], ...

Comment: in my opinion this answer is way too lengthy

Comment: I agree, looking now at how to make it shorter.

Comment: I doubt this rule fits here.

Comment: @AlexVB, then suggest one that fits better :)